# MS Office for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, microsoft-office

I have been using Ubuntu for two months now, and I am loving it. However, I cannot install MS Office 2013/2016, which I need! I couldn't install it with Wine. Please don't tell me to use LibreOffice or MS Office Online. They suck when it comes to document formatting.

So if anyone has found something for this, please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried WPS Office yet?

Comment: @edwinksl Why not LibreOffice? I use it every day and now I'm wondering if I'm missing out on something....

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix OP specifically said he/she doesn't want to use LibreOffice.

Comment: @edwinksi Sorry I missed the "they such at formatting" statement. I've actually noticed that a couple of times especially with large documents. I guess I should give WPS a look myself soon since you recommended it and are prone to good advice.

Comment: Wps office is much better and exact copy of ms office..still if u want ms using crossover or wine it can be installed

Comment: Bad strategy. If you really wish to leave the world of Microsoft behind you should shift to [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/).

Comment: @LuísdeSousa [please be careful when flagging](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15921/85695). There's nothing rude or abusive here.

Comment: terdon perhaps you should read a bit more on the origin and meaning of the word [suck](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/suck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, MS Office 2013/2016 requires DirectX 10. Unfortunately, as of Wine 1.9, DirectX 10 is not supported.

Sorry, you will have to use LibreOffice, MS Office 2007, or WPS Office.

Edit: You CAN use a VM to run Windows to run MS Office. However, this is quite a bit more time consuming and resource-intensive than simply a) dual-booting Windows or b) using Libre/WPS Office.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I wasn't aware we could run Office 7 via wine :) 
I am using that on wine now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are options to use the Microsoft Office package suite for popular software like Word, Excel, Powerpoint, Publisher, Outlook, and so on.
I personally recommend option 3
There are always many ways of achieving goals

## 1. Using Wine application

There is an option to use the Wine application on Ubuntu that allows you to install Windows .exe files in Ubuntu.

To install Wine, use the following commands:

## Enable multiarch

`$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

## Update the repositories

`$ sudo apt update`

## Install wine

`$ sudo apt install wine64 wine32`

## Check wine version

`$ wine --version`

For other Ubuntu versions, like 20.04,

## Enable multiarch and update

`$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
`$ sudo apt update`
Import WineHQ repository's key
`$ wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -`
Add WineHQ to the system
`$ sudo apt install software-properties-common`
`$ sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"`
Install Wine
`$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

## Check wine version

`$ wine --version`

You can configure your wine application by typing in the terminal
`$ winecfg`
Add Q4Wine install
`$ sudo apt-get install -y q4wine`
when you search your applications, you should be able to see the Q4Wine there.

## 2. Playonlinux

Add repository to package list
`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps`
Update the package list
`$ sudo apt update`
Install playonlinux
`$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

## 3. OneDrive online

I really recommend this as it offers all options available when using MsOffice in Windows than in Linux.
When using MsOffice in Ubuntu, standard fonts like Times New Roman is not available in the base operating system but using One Drive, offers those great options.
steps:
Use this link:
`https://onedrive.live.com/`
login | signup using your Microsoft or Google accounts,
follow the popup option.
If you need the Microsoft Authenticator app, download it to your phone from Google Playstore
Use this link: 
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azure.authenticator&hl=en&gl=US`

Register your details as required.
When using One Drive, you can save documents online or locally by downloading the document you created. It maintains the format as created even if it is on Linux.
Thanks for reading through this article. Hope it solves your problems.